# ZK Comboobox with a predefined set value

Tags: combobox, zk

I want to create in ZK a simple combobox with 2 items: true and false. The combobox should have as a default set value the true item. Although it seems straightforward, I haven't managed to find a single online resource that explains such a simple component.

The code is displayed below:

```
<combobox id="validateVoucher" hflex="2">
    <comboitem id="true" label="True"/>
    <comboitem id="false" label="False"/>
</combobox>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is it OK, to set id to true or false? I think you can simply set the value attribute of the combobox tag to the default value.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean

Comment: first i think you can't use true or false as ids. Second, if you want to set a default value to your combobox just use the value attribute. <combobox  value="true"  >.

Answer (score 4):

The following is tested:

```
<combobox id="validateVoucher" hflex="2" value="True">
    <comboitem label="True" value="true" />
    <comboitem label="False" value="false" />
</combobox>
```

There are a couple of things to note here.
First and foremost is that `true` and `false` are not valid ids. If you're using ZKStudio it'll give you a warning

> Syntax error on token "true", invalid VariableDeclaratorId

Everything still works as expected, unexpectedly, but warnings shouldn't be ignored.

If you're intention of setting the `id` was to store some useful 'data' to be retrieved later, the correct way to do this is to use the `value` field. This is the same as in HTML, read more on the HTML `select` tag for best practices.

Lastly, as Prabhat suggested, you can predefine the selected comboitem by specifying the `value` in the `combobox`. Note here, that the `value` field in the `combobox` **does not** map to the `value` field on the `comboitem`.

What you're actually doing here is setting the default displayed value of the `combobox`, which ZK will then map to a `label` on one of the `comboitem`s. To better understand this, consider if you set the `value` of the `combobox` to 'gobbledigook'. The `combobox` will render with that text but when you expand the drop-down menu, neither 'True' nor 'False' will be preselected.

**Extra 2 cents:**

If you only want the user to be able to select 'True' or 'False', set `readonly=true` on the `combobox`

Comment: Good, detailed answer and extra points for readonly=false suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this :

```
<combobox id="validateVoucher" value="True" hflex="2">
    <comboitem id="true" label="True"/>
    <comboitem id="false" label="False"/>
</combobox>
```

Please do comment does it work ?